# orientdb kubernetes readiness probe errored: gzip : invalid header

Tags: docker, kubernetes, orientdb, minikube

I am trying to create an orient db deployment on kubernetes cluster using the following yaml file using the orientdb:2.125 docker image from docker hub.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orientdb
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: orientdb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 100
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: orientdb
    spec:
      containers:
        # Custom pod name.
      - name: orientdb-node
        image: orientdb:2.1.25
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 2480 # WEB port number.
        - name: binary-port
          containerPort: 2424
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: http-port
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: http-port
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 5
```

But I am getting the following message

```
Readiness probe errored: gzip: invalid header
Liveness probe errored: gzip: invalid header
```

How do I fix the readiness and liveness probe for orient db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

orientdb web application on port 2480 returns gzipped HTTP response, so you should add custom HTTP headers to support this into your `httpGet` livenessProbe and readinessProbe:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http-port
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Accept-Encoding
      value: gzip
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
  timeoutSeconds: 30
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http-port
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Accept-Encoding
      value: gzip
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```